# How to do I clear a one to one relationship in a Django model?

Tags: django

I am using a one to one relationship between two models and I need to be able to clear that relationship.  However, I cannot find a way to clear(clear(), remove(), etc...) it to remove that relationship, and the Django admin will not perform that operation.  Does anyone have experience with this problem?  I think I may have to skip the one to one field and use a one to many with unique=true set on the field.

Edit: I should have mentioned.  I do have null=True set on the field, but it does not make a difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just set it to None and save :-)

```
my_instance.my_one_to_one_fieldname = None
my_instance.save()
```

edit: By the way, this only works for the model that you defined the `OneToOneField` on. I'm not sure how you would go about doing this backwards, except for:

```
my_related_instance.othermodel.my_one_to_one_fieldname = None
my_related_instance.othermodel.save()
```

But that's just the same as doing:

```
my_instance = my_related_instance.othermodel
```

and then continuing like the first example.

Answer (score 1):

If `null=True` is specified for the field you should be able to do an `Instance.<foreignmodel>_set.clear()` I might be off on this..

Comment: Ya, I did, I should have mentioned it.  That doesn't make a difference.  You also don't get set like object(Instance.<foreignmodel>_set) to reference with a one to one relation ship.